# Splitting Column Conditionally in R

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

My data frame looks something like this:

```
Var
H2307
A123
F45fjhsk
category
J30HS
```

And I'd like it to look like this:

```
Var       Var_1       Var_2
H2307     H           2307
A123      A           123
F45fjhsk  NA          NA
category  NA          NA
J30HS     J           30HS
```

I have tried variations of this:

```
for (i in 1:length(dat$Var)){
   if (nchar(dat$Var) < 7){
     tx <- strsplit(dat$Var[i], split = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl = T)
     tx <- t(matrix(tx, nrow=2, ncol=length(tx)/2))
   }
 }
```

which is getting close I think but still doesn't work; the splitting part works pretty fine. I have the "< 7" because all the strings I want to split are less than 7 characters, so it excludes the "F45fjhsk" entry.

Comment: Your before's/after's don't have any logic, perhaps you could explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyr::extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% 
    extract(Var, into=c("Var_1", "Var_2"), regex="^(?=.{1,7}$)([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9].*)$", remove=FALSE)
df

#       Var Var_1 Var_2
#1    H2307     H  2307
#2     A123     A   123
#3 F45fjhsk  <NA>  <NA>
#4 category  <NA>  <NA>
#5    J30HS     J  30HS
```

`^(?=.{1,7}$)` [asserts the total number of characters](https://imbibe.in/blog/2016/06/27/regex-using-positive-lookahead-assertion-limit-total-string-lengths/) to be less than or equal to seven; `([a-zA-Z]+)` matches the non digits part from the beginning of the string; `([0-9].*)` matches everything after the first digit.

Comment: Can you explain what does `"^(?=.{1,7}$)"` is for?

Comment: When I run this, there are no errors, but the data frame seems to be unchanged which is weird

Comment: Did you assign the result back to `df`? `extract` doesn't modify `df` in place but return a new one.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your regEx is excluding the possibility of having letters in the second group

```
([a-zA-Z])(.+)
```

By using (.+) in the second collection, you will be able to handle that case also.

Comment: @Chi Pak which according to his example set he wants to handle. His current regex would exclude that row, and I am suggesting an update to include it by using .+ instead of [0-9]

Comment: Updated to hopefully clarify

Comment: When I run the regEx portion alone without the "for" or "if" statement it seems to split each value just fine. However, because of some of the weird long entries in the Var column, it makes two or three splits sometimes, but I want those long entries to be NAs anyways so I thought having the "nchar<7" would do the trick since all the entries < 7 follow a similar pattern

Comment: There are some other potential cases that may come up that you may need to consider how to properly handle like the following:
`Fish4
TG45Ed`